# onActivityResult is not calling while using facebook login in android

Tags: android, facebook, onactivityresult

I have integrated Facebook and created app in Facebook developer account. I have registerd FBHelper activity in facebook developer account, Once i received data/facebook details , i used setResult method but it is not calling the onActivityResult() method of LoginActivity.java.

**code:
LoginAcitivity.java**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, FBHelper.class);

                startActivityForResult(intent,2);
```

onActivityResult() of LoginActivity.java

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


       if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            String jsondata=data.getStringExtra("userProfile");
            try {


                JSONObject response = new JSONObject(jsondata);
                String email = (response.get("email").toString());
                String fname = (response.get("first_name").toString());
                String lname = (response.get("last_name").toString());
                String id = (response.get("id").toString());
                Toast.makeText(loginActivity,"facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Social_Login(email, id, fname, lname, "facebook");

            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
}
```

FBHelper.java

```
public class FBHelper extends AppCompatActivity {
CallbackManager callbackManager;
private CallbackManager mFacebookCallbackManager;
private Context myActivity;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fb_helper);
    try {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        boolean isLoggedIn = accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired();
       LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(FBHelper.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
        LoginManager.getInstance().setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.DEVICE_AUTH);


        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                getUserDetails(loginResult);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
                Log.v("onCancel", "onCancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
                exception.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("onError", "CANCEL");
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected void getUserDetails(LoginResult loginResult) {
    GraphRequest data_request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(
                        JSONObject json_object, GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                        returnIntent.putExtra("userProfile", json_object.toString());
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                       // LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                        finish();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            });
    try {
        Bundle permission_param = new Bundle();
        permission_param.putString("fields", "id,name,email,picture.width(120).height(120)");
        data_request.setParameters(permission_param);
        data_request.executeAsync();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Logs 'app deactivate' App Event.
    AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
}
```

}

Comment: check your request code. you sending request code as 2. but in onactivityResult checked condition as 223

Comment: Manivasagam  Kindly check the code i have updated. I have change the request code but it is not working.

Comment: in FBHelper class getUserDetails() method check what response getting in this line returnIntent.putExtra("userProfile", json_object.toString());

Comment: ok. could u remove above your comment because your personal data is available

Comment: check with debug mode LoginActivity.java onActivityresult what you getting requestCode and any exception

Comment: It is not moving to LoginActivity after calling setResult in FBHelper.java..No Exception

Comment: FBHelper activity getting finish or not??

Comment: if i write finish() then it finishes otherwise not. i used log message it is printing after setResult of FBHelper.java.

Comment: we need to add finish after setResult(). add one break point in if(requestCode==2)  and check what response is coming for request code and data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally i got the solution, I started from scratch with another Activity and slowly duplicated the new activity till it matched the one that was breaking. In short, it was nothing to do with the Activity but the Android Manifest.

**In my Android Manifest, I had android:noHistory="true" on my LoginActivity which was crashing my app. Once I removed it then it worked again.**

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activity.General.LoginActivity"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try removing the onActivityResult method from the FBHelper.java